# View transition

Tags: ios, view, transition

In modalTransitionStyle there are currently 4 existing styles, I am wondering how can I program my own transition?

I have seen this app called flipboard and it's got this amazing transition , any help would be highly appreciated

A

Answer (score 1):

You may animate transition programmatically in viewDidAppear/viewWillDisappear methods any way you like. However you should do it for each view with custom transition.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, how do u make custom transition, that's basically my question. Is there a class or a framework that works on individual pixels of the view?

Answer (score 0):

**I would recommed you to look at [this tutorial](http://maniacdev.com/2010/09/tutorial-creating-a-custom-transition-with-core-animation/) and [this stackoverflow question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060551/getting-started-creating-custom-view-transitions).**

Comment: Hey guys, i checked out the tuts you said and it works perfectly, NoI've got much worse problem, the transitions work perfectly when it is in portrait mode but not in the landscape mode. The whole CALayer thing and its method "contentRect" don't seem to work properly in the landcape mode. I have my files in here..